# Where can I find a free/cheap corpus of the 20,000 most frequently used words in the English language?

Tags: corpora

There are a bunch of large corpora containing millions or billions of words.

My needs are simpler: I only need the 20K most used words. Preferably, these words should be most used in the general social media population, but any corpus will do as long as it consists primarily of words used in the last 10 years and as long as academic journals don't count.

COCA looks good but has more words than I need and costs more for a commercial license than I'd like to pay.

Comment: If it's important that it be from specifically the last ten years, I'd recommend putting that in the title. I can think of plenty of free corpora, but most of them include content that's older than that.

Comment: See also this question and its answers: https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/q/33565/9781

Comment: a corpus typically contains entire texts, not individual words. Do you mean a corpus, or do you just want a wordlist?